# Get the right value of select box and display it in php

Tags: php, forms, select, box

I have a form with a select box where the user can select his gender. I succeed in getting the selected value and displaying this. But I want to use another term for the selected value.

For example, there are 2 values in the select box, named "man" and "vrouw".

```
<select name="geslacht" class="formulier-input">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Kies uw geslacht</option>
    <option value="man">Man</option>
    <option value="vrouw">Vrouw</option>
</select>
```

But I want to display Dhr. as the user selects for the value "man" and Mevr. as the user selects for the value "vrouw".

I guess I can do this in an if statement with:

```
if($geslacht === "the value"){ }
```

I don't know how I can finish this and I don't know what to put in the place of "the value".
How can I do this?

Comment: `if ($_POST['geslacht'] == 'man') { ... }`

Comment: `<option value="man">Dhr.</option>` and `<option value="vrouw">Mevr.</option>` or reversed as I don't quite understand.

Comment: ensure your form has a `method='post'` you can then capture it as `$_POST['geslacht']`

Comment: It does, I just don't know how to write the if statemtent to get the right value